# How can I create an extruded curved wall?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am (completely) new to Blender, but I have a lot of experience with engineering 3D model software. I made the following in [Inventor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Inventor), but exactly what would be the standard way to achieve this in Blender?

[image]

I am struggling with whether it should be one object, where the block has had the curved section extruded from its surface. Or whether it should be two objects.

I also am struggling with how to create the two concentric arcs.

Comment: so do you want it to be one or 2 objects?

Comment: @moonboots I am not experienced enough with Blender to know what difference it will make, I'm afraid, and why I should care if it is 1 or 2 objects. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! A couple of good concepts to understand in general are: **1.** An **object** is like a *container* that holds your geometry. While in Edit Mode it's like you're poking around inside the container and changing the contents. When you move your object, its contents go with it. **2.** Most objects contain *mesh data* (polygons). Some contain *curve data* (vector paths). There are other types of objects too. If you make a *Linked Duplicate* you'll end up with a second object shat shares the same inside data. A regular *Duplicate* has unique data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have no particular reason to do it with one mesh, do it with 2 separate meshes (or 2 separate objects), as it will be much simpler. For the curvy wall, create a cube, keep only an angle, select the angle edge:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel, use the mouse wheel to add segments, or type the parameters in the *Operator* box (at the bottom left of the 3D view):

[image]

Select all, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> *(Extrude)* and choose *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

For the floor, create a plane, scale it, extrude on Z.

If you want to easily change the wall thickness, don't extrude, use a *Solidify* modifier and tweak the *Thickness* value:

[image]

Only apply the modifier when you're sure about the thickness (you need to be in *Object* mode to apply):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just out of interest - if I wanted to come back later and change the thickness of the wall, how would I do it? If I select the outer faces and then try to extrude along normals back the other way (in an attempt to reduce the wall thickness), then it cuts inside the wall, leaving theend caps in tact.

Comment: In that case maybe don't extrude and use a Solidify modifier instead, see my edit

Comment: Great, this is useful to know! Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 6):

I would add a plane, go to edit mode, press <kbd>E</kbd> and move your mouse like this:

[image]

Then select these:

[image]

Press <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> and move your mouse:

[image]

In object mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>: *Curve* → *Arc*

Change the angle to 90 like this:

[image]

Now press <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> -90

[image]

And with <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> move your arc:

[image]

Select the last vertex:

[image]

Press <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> and move the mouse:

[image]

In object mode, add another curve → rectangle.

[image]

And in your arc object, choose bevel-object: rectangle.

[image]

Now choose your rectangle again and size it to your needs:

[image]

Select "fill caps":

[image: Anter image description here]

And with object → convert → to mesh, you can turn it into a mesh and select "autosmooth":

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, either answer would solve my problem - the one above just seemed to be quicker, with fewer steps. Thank you.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out, but it seems like you need to enable an "Add On" to get the "arc" option that you used, right?

Comment: That’s right ‼️‼️‼️

Comment: Thanks. In your answer, you have a step which says "and in your arc object choose bevel-object: rectangle". Is this an option that should be found somewhere after selecting the arc and going into Edit Mode? Thanks so much for your patience :)

Comment: If you click on the curve symbol of the arc (curved line with 2 rectangles in green) you can see a bevel section (maybe you have to oben it by clicking) , then click on „object“ and then you can choose anno object

Comment: Yep, got it. That option was a little hidden! Great, it works now, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome