# How can I fix the image texture problem on this curved wall?

Tags: texturing, uv, subdivision-surface

I am a complete Blender beginner and am having a problem with texturing a curved wall (a follow on from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/267974/150802)). Following [this modelling tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px0sJElIUGc), I have created the wall from several cube mesh elements:

[image]

and then added a subdivision surface modifier to make the large face smoothly curved:

[image]

Note that I have added extra edge loops to keep some of the edges sharper:

[image]

The model seems to work nicely as far as I can tell, but I can't figure out what is going wrong when trying to apply an image texture. The UV view looks like this:

[image]

I tried making the ends of the wall [*Seams*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/seams.html) as well, but that didn't seem to help.

After trying "Reset" on the UV unwrap, I get the following, which has the bricks at the top and bottom of the wall more squashed than those in the middle:

[image]

What's the explanation for the funny shapes I see in the UV editor, and how what's the correct way to fix it?

---

**Edit**

After the answer from @Jakemoyo, I have added seams to the top and bottom, which definitely helps, and turned on "UV Smooth: All" in the subdivision modifier:

[image]

However, the pieces in the UV Editor window are all skewed, which leads to the bricks not being aligned parallel with the floor.

File here:
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: go to https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you only have seams on the ends of your model. When you're UV unwrapping you want to put seams in location such that the entire model could "unfold" and lay with the back of each face "against" the texture.

Looking at this section of the model; without any seams here how can you expect the model to unfold like that?

[image]

However if you put seams here,  you can unwrap this model with seams like this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

And then adjust the UVs with the help of the TexTools addon to get something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see that seams along the top and bottom may now be needed. Do I need to "apply" the subdivision surface modifier before UV unwrapping, or can it remain unapplied?

Comment: I have added seams to the top and bottom as you suggest, but my pieces in teh UV editor window are all skewed, whereas yours are rectangular. See edit in question.

Comment: Install the [TexTools addon](https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender). Use the rectify function to correct that. Also UV unwrapping meshes with unapplied modifiers can give unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Note (for anyone else) that I managed to fix it without using TexTools. First trick was to set the UV unwrap to "conformal", which fixed the skew/distortion. Then the curved pieces can be straightened out by using the"Follow Active Quads" trick (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHbgQs8zkpw)

Comment: That function in textools is the same as the Follow active quads, just fewer steps. Textools is a must have for UVs in blender, basically like node wrangler. Like if you don't have that then what are you even doing.